# How to pull data from Service to Activity?

Tags: android, service

Im working on my first app with service. I have created normal android service that handles GPS and few other things. Everything seem to work but... I don't know how to interact with that service from Activity.

My service class holds `User` class, and that class holds current GPS position and some other variables.

```
public class PxService extends Service
{
    public static final User user;
...

}
```

**My goal is to access `User` class (or members) from activity.**

My service is not bound service, because I want it to run when my app is closed (as far I know bound service cannot work when app is not running, but maybe I'm wrong).

Any help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can saving User in database.
Or you can Implement for User class interface Parcelable (or Serializable) and flush user object in intent BroadcastReciever like that:

in service

```
Intent intent = new Intent("YOUR_ACTION);
intent.putExtra("user", user);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and in BroadcastReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("YOUR_ACTION")) {
        User user = (User) intent.getParcelableExtra("user);
    }
}
```

Don't forget register your broadcastreciever.

This is simple article how to using this method.
http://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/

UPDATE

Comment by this "*as far I know bound service cannot work when app is not running, but maybe I'm wrong*". You can use Service method `startForeground(int id, Notification notification)`

Documentation:

> Make this service run in the foreground, supplying the ongoing
>   notification to be shown to the user while in this state. By default
>   services are background, meaning that if the system needs to kill them
>   to reclaim more memory (such as to display a large page in a web
>   browser), they can be killed without too much harm.  You can set this
>   flag if killing your service would be disruptive to the user, such as
>   if your service is performing background music playback, so the user
>   would notice if their music stopped playing.

Comment: But I want that data to be available "on Activity demand", not "when service broadcasts it"...

Comment: Notifies service via same broadcast) which will initiate the sending user by other broadcast))

Comment: I do not know essentially of your problem. Maybe better method be a an Activity call startService, and wait until service work all it needed and returns User?